# How can I make hover on a static window?

Tags: c++, winapi

Currently only WM_MOUSEMOVE works. The image changes, but WM_MOUSELEAVE doesn't work anymore.
I want to make a hover effect on the button. What am I doing wrong?

```
[...]
hWndButton= CreateWindowW(L"Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP | 
SS_NOTIFY, 10, 25, 109, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)4, NULL, NULL);
[...]
bool TheButtonToggle = false;
[...]
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

            if (TheButtonToggle == false) {
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tm_Event;
                tm_Event.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tm_Event.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
                tm_Event.hwndTrack = GetDlgItem((HWND)dwRefData, IDB_BUTTON);
                TrackMouseEvent(&tm_Event);
                TheButtonToggle = true;

                HBITMAP hbmpButtonHover = LoadBitmap(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_HOVER_BUTTON));
                SendMessage(hWndButton, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hbmpButtonHover);
            }
            break;

        case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        {
            HBITMAP hbmpButton = LoadBitmap(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BUTTON));
            SendMessage(hWndButton, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hbmpButton);

            TheButtonToggle = false;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: *"I want to make a hover effect on the button."* - It would appear natural to pass `TME_HOVER` into [TRACKMOUSEEVENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-trackmouseevent) for that.

Comment: @IInspectable ok, I changed in WM_MOUSEMOVE tm_Event.dwFlags = TME_HOVER; but WM_MOUSELEAVE still doesn't work.

Comment: The `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is sent to the window being tracked, that is, the window you pass in the `hwndTrack` member.. You are handling `WM_MOUSELEAVE` in the wrong window.

Comment: You can subclass a button to monitor mouse move, if mouse move on the button, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message in the subclass callback function will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

You can subclass a button to monitor mouse move, if mouse move on the button, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message in the subclass callback function will be triggered.

```
hWndButton = CreateWindowW(L"Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP |
       SS_NOTIFY, 10, 25, 109, 30, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);

SetWindowSubclass(hWndButton, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, IDC_BUTTON, 0);

[...]



LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {           
        HBITMAP hbmpButton = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
        SendMessage(hWndButton, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hbmpButton);
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, 1);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: @PabloRoves Hi, Is the answer useful to you?